# How can I use this background image for all aspect ratio?

Tags: android, image, android-layout, background, aspect-ratio

I have an image like this used as **background** in a RelativeLayout:

[image]

This image is used as background for all the levels of my game. Every level is drawn onto the blue area.
I want to keep fixed the **aspect-ratio** of the **blue area**, changing the size of the **red edges** to avoid to show to the user unused pixels of their screen. The **green area** must be fixed to 80dp for all phones. Then I must add a View (a GLSurfaceView) in my layout in such a way that it fit perfectly the blue area. Thus all levels of my Android game will be perfectly the same in all Android device.

**How can I solve this problem?**

The real image that I use is a little more complex. You can look it here:

[Real image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o7Tnm.png)

Answer (score 0):

I would use a FrameLayout for the middle part of the screen(blue), add an ImageView, containing the BackgroundImage you want to display, and put the GLSurfaceView on top of it.

Since the aspect ratio is always the same, you could set the ImageViews sclaing to fit xy and the image should always look the same.

Lets assume you are using a simple SurfaceView, the xml code id use to put a ImageView begind it would look like this

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

   <ImageView 
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"/>

    <SurfaceView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</FrameLayout>
```

As i dont know how you build your View i cant post the code that does the job, but just add a FrameLayout instead of your GLSurfaceView to your View, with the Same Dimensions, the GLSurfaceView would have.

To that FrameLayout first add the ImageView, then the GLSurfaceView. Both with height and width set to match_parent.

To Figure out the size of your SurfaceView...

1. Retrieve Display Dimensions
2. Substract Green Bar Dimensions
3. Calculate the size of the Blue View, get the Height/Width (whatever is bigger) calculate the missing Dimension
4. Set the Red Views to Occupie the empty space.

So you would have to do this programmatically :)

Comment: Mmm, I can't use this method because my real image is more complex than the image in the question. Look my real image, I edited the question.

Comment: I really dont see any problem, even with the real Image. If you can be sure that the aspect ratio is fix, there is no problem i could think of. Just Wrap the GLSurfaceView as i suggested or let me know what seems to be the problem since i cant think of any.

Comment: So maybe I did not understand your answer. Can you be more detailed please? Thank you ...

Comment: "with the Same Dimensions, the GLSurfaceView would have." The problem is that I don't know the dimensions of the GLSurfaceView, I know only its aspect ratio.

Comment: Ah sorry, i thought that you already figured out how to do that :)

Comment: added how i would do it, but not gonna code that one, since its more coding than i want to do right now :p

Comment: But if I set the image as background in the ImageView inside the  FrameLayout and the FrameLayout has the same dimensions that the GLSurfaceView would have, how can the GLSurfaceView  fit perfectly the blue area? The ImageView and the GLSurface have same dimensions and my image background is one.

Comment: You could also set the image as background of the FrameLayout. just noticed, but i still dont get your problem.
Do you know how a FrameLayout works? ^^